# Developing a game

Tags: android

iam using libgdx for developing a touch based game.In my game i would like to save the state and want to restore it at some particular time. Is there any way in libgdx or any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by saving state you mean saving and loading settings/preferences, use [this](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1585):

```
Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("my-preferences");
prefs.putBoolean("bool", true);
prefs.putInteger("int", 1234);
prefs.putLong("long", Long.MAX_VALUE);
prefs.putFloat("float", 1.2345f);
prefs.putString("string", "test!");

if(prefs.getBoolean("bool") != true) throw new GdxRuntimeException("bool failed");
if(prefs.getInteger("int") != 1234) throw new GdxRuntimeException("int failed");
if(prefs.getLong("long") != Long.MAX_VALUE) throw new GdxRuntimeException("long failed");
if(prefs.getFloat("float") != 1.2345f) throw new GdxRuntimeException("float failed");
if(!prefs.getString("string").equals("test!")) throw new GdxRuntimeException("string failed");
```

Comment: saving the state in the sense, for example, if a rock falls from the top to bottm, then i should replace it back to the position where it has fallen from. for this scenario i need help.